# asp.net windows azure blob storage

Tags: asp.net

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(RoleEnvironment.GetConfigurationSettingValue("blobconn"));

            CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();


            // Retrieve a reference to a container 
            CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("mamta");

//everything fine till here ; next line creates an exception :( wat to do

            // Create the container if it doesn't already exist
            container.CreateIfNotExist();
        }
```

Comment: Just wondering... and...? Add a bit more detail about what you are trying to achieve - the actual exception thrown would be useful, too ;-). For example, are you sure there is something in the cloud with the container reference "mamta"?

Comment: What do you want here? Can you explain a bit more???

Comment: This post is not a question, so I will try to close it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create blob then you can use following code. Put this code in webrole.cs or workrole.cs file methode name "OnStart()" which is located in Azure project.

```
 string ContainerName = "Blob Name";
 public void createBlob()
    {
        try
        {
            CloudStorageAccount.SetConfigurationSettingPublisher((configName, configSetter) =>
            {
                // Provide the configSetter with the initial value
                configSetter(RoleEnvironment.GetConfigurationSettingValue(configName));

                RoleEnvironment.Changed += (sender, arg) =>
                {
                    if (arg.Changes.OfType<RoleEnvironmentConfigurationSettingChange>()
                        .Any((change) => (change.ConfigurationSettingName == configName)))
                    {
                        // The corresponding configuration setting has changed, propagate the value
                        if (!configSetter(RoleEnvironment.GetConfigurationSettingValue(configName)))
                        {
                            RoleEnvironment.RequestRecycle();
                        }
                    }
                };
            });

            // read account configuration settings
            var storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.FromConfigurationSetting("Your Azure Local storage Connection string");

            // create blob container for images
            blobStorage = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
            container = blobStorage.GetContainerReference(ContainerName);
            container.CreateIfNotExist();


            // configure container for public access
            var permissions = container.GetPermissions();
            permissions.PublicAccess = BlobContainerPublicAccessType.Container;
            container.SetPermissions(permissions);

            // create queue to communicate with worker role
            queueStorage = storageAccount.CreateCloudQueueClient();
            CloudQueue queue = queueStorage.GetQueueReference("guestthumbs");
            queue.CreateIfNotExist();


        }
        catch (WebException)
        {
            throw new WebException("Storage services initialization failure. "
                + "Check your storage account configuration settings. If running locally, "
                + "ensure that the Development Storage service is running.");
        }

        //storageInitialized = true;           
    }
```

If you're not using Azure project then see this blog article:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg651129.aspx